# Dummy Request Response for Servlet testing

Tags: unit-testing, servlets

How to Create a Dummy Request and Response for Servlet Testing.I read about the Apache Jkarta Cactus Project but do not want to go in that much details. Can we just construct a dummy request response and pass it to doGet() method (Ofcourse the request constructed would have a URL and request parameters, but how to construct such dummy request)?

and also want no dependency of junit on Apache(should run independent of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into MockHTTPServletRequest(), I think its going to work. [Here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html) is the link which you can read.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` are just interfaces, so you can easily implement them yourself and use them in unit tests.

Of course, the various methods on these interfaces interrelate, especially in the request, so it's trickier than it first looks.

Some frameworks come with [test implementations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html) of those interfaces. For example Spring comes with `MockHttpServletRequest` and `MockHttpServletResponse` classes which have comprehensive sensible implementations of these interfaces.

Alternatively, you can use a mock object framework (of which Java has many... jmock, mockito, easymock to name but 3) which allow you to just implement the methods you're interested in.

Comment: When I try to implement these interfaces , it  asks me to implement a lot of methods. What I need is just to set a URL and some parameters and request type like GET,POST. 
and Can you provide some link to read about jmock, mockito, easymock?

Comment: @rm21: I just gave you 2 alternatives to implementing the interface yourself. The mock frameworks all have their own webpages with tutorials.

Comment: ya will take a look at them..
Also I was looking into [this](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/servletunit-intro.html).
Is it that the junit test for servlet will need apache to run? Because I want that as I run by build file using ant , I should get my junit outputs

Comment: @rm21: HttpUnit is a framework for testing websites, not for unit tests of code.